# Cannot import seaborn [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-notebook

I am trying to import seaborn in my notebook [part of ArcGIS Pro] and I get [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found error.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [3]:
Line 1:     import seaborn as sns

File C:\Users\borou\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\ArcGIS_1\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py, in <module>:
Line 2:     from .rcmod import *  # noqa: F401,F403

File C:\Users\borou\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\ArcGIS_1\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py, in <module>:
Line 7:     from . import palettes

File C:\Users\borou\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\ArcGIS_1\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py, in <module>:
Line 9:     from .utils import desaturate, get_color_cycle

File C:\Users\borou\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\ArcGIS_1\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py, in <module>:
Line 10:    from scipy import stats

File C:\Users\borou\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\ArcGIS_1\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py, in <module>:
Line 136:   from . import _distributor_init

File C:\Users\borou\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\ArcGIS_1\lib\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py, in <module>:
Line 59:    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))

File C:\Users\borou\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\ArcGIS_1\lib\ctypes\__init__.py, in __init__:
Line 364:   self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: Is it a cloned env or the default one? Also, did you check if the module is available in the current environment?

Comment: Yes, I am running it on a clone environment. It turned out that with pip installation it works! I believe pip doesn't update the dependencies. @YogeshChavan